# Prevent login from login observer in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, customer, login

Trying to prevent registered users from logging in based on their customer group id. I have this working in magento 1, however I haven't been successful in replicating it on magento2. Any help is appreciated.

Magento 1

```
public function customerlogin($observer)
{
   $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
   $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

   if ($customer->getData('group_id') == 2)
   {
    $session->setId(null)
       ->setCustomerGroupId(Mage_Customer_Model_Group::NOT_LOGGED_IN_ID)
       ->getCookie()->delete('customer');

    Mage::throwException(__('Login not allowed'));
    return;
}
```

}

Magento 2 - unfinished

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $event      = $observer->getEvent();
    $customer   = $event->getCustomer();
    if($customer->getGroupId() == '2'){
        $this->messageManager->addNotice(__('Login not allowed'));
        //prevent login
    }
}
```

Comment: Which event you try to catch?

Comment: <event name="customer_login">

Comment: See my answer. We should try with Plugin way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look into:

```
vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/Login.php

vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Ajax/Login.php
```

Magento will use `\Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement::authenticate()` to authenticate a customer by username and password. We should try Plugin with this method.

app/code/Vendor/Customer/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface">
        <plugin name="check_customer_group" type="Vendor\Customer\Plugin\AccountManagement" />
    </type>
</config>
```

app/code/Vendor/Customer/Plugin/AccountManagement.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Customer\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class AccountManagement
{
    const BLACK_LIST_CUSTOMER_GROUP = 4;

    /**
     * Authenticate a customer
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $result
     * @return \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function afterAuthenticate(
        \Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement,
        $result
    )
    {
        if($result->getGroupId() == self::BLACK_LIST_CUSTOMER_GROUP) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('The customer group does not allow.'));
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Remember to create `module.xml` and `registration.php` file.